# Different number of files when I make an application using self-contained

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

When I use the publish wizard built into VS 2019 all the files I require are created (271 files). There are the files System..dll, api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll etc.

[image]

However, when I use the command below, I only have 60 files and unfortunately the Windows Service application will not work. What do I need to add to the command so that the number of files is the same as that produced by the publishing wizard ?

`dotnet publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:self-contained=true /p:framework=net5.0 /p:runtime=win-x64 /p:Platform="Any CPU"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following dotnet publish format:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --self-contained true --framework net5.0 --output "C:\Users\YourUserName\YOUR_RELEASE_FOLDER" --runtime win-x64
```

Comment: Additionally, can you post the error details you have please. Ty.

Comment: Also, it is important to run the command from the same location in which we have the solution file (.sln) so it can pick all the projects that are included in the solution. Providing, all projects were added into the sln file IF the solution was developed using VSCode instead of VS2019.

Comment: There is no error message

Comment: A different format for "dotnet publish" works. Why does the same thing written differently already work without a problem?

Comment: Cool! Good to know it helped. I believe most likely, you are running the command from within your pipeline which runs on a win server that does some odd ascii encoding while reading the escaped character "/p". Thus, producing some unexpected results. Using, the --param in the dotnet cli should fix the issue and it should be the latest format of using the dotnet cli.